# Could not find method android.view.View.getParentForAccessibility

Tags: android, view, imagebutton, onclicklistener

Getting the following error onclick of minus remove button:

> Could not find method android.view.View.getParentForAccessibility,
>   referenced from method com.wassap.main.UserFragment$12.onClick

Relevant code:

```
/////////////////////// minus remove button click
    imgRemove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
     @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onClick(View vv) 
        {
    View parent = (View) vv.getParentForAccessibility();
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

`getParentForAccessibility` is available since `Android 16`. So you need a device with at least that api level to run it

Comment: But my api level is `Android 17` and I am still getting this error.

Comment: the device in which you are testing this code what versione of android has?

Comment: On Device `Android Version 4.0.4`

Comment: oh yes that is why it is working with `Android Version 4.1.1` but what should I do in order to make it work for `Android Version 4.0.4` ?

Comment: it is not so simply to accomplish. I will start grepcode in order to check if the method could easily ported

Comment: Any clue what method to use equivalent to it for lower level api's. I want to make the code run for all api levels or most.